# Android Studio Bottom Bar Nav: How do I add to each fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I followed a tutorial online to create a Bottom Bar `Navigation`, but the guy didn't explain clearly how to add stuff to each fragment and swap between the fragments. I want to add an `EditText` to the home page as an example on how to add items to the fragments. Here's my code:

**Main Activity -**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_CATA = "tag_frag_cata";
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME = "tag_frag_home";
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_SETTINGS = "tag_frag_settings";

private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

private List<BottomBarFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(3);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.bottombaritem_cata:
                                switchFragment(0, TAG_FRAGMENT_CATA);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.bottombaritem_home:
                                switchFragment(1, TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.bottombaritem_settings:
                                switchFragment(2, TAG_FRAGMENT_SETTINGS);
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        buildFragmentsList();

        switchFragment(1, TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME);

    }

    private void buildFragmentsList() {
        BottomBarFragment cataFragment = buildFragment("Categories");
        BottomBarFragment homeFragment = buildFragment("Home");
        BottomBarFragment settingsFragment = buildFragment("Settings");

        fragments.add(cataFragment);
        fragments.add(homeFragment);
        fragments.add(settingsFragment);
    }

    private BottomBarFragment buildFragment(String title) {
        BottomBarFragment fragment = new BottomBarFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BottomBarFragment.ARG_TITLE, title);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void switchFragment(int pos, String tag) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_fragmentholder, fragments.get(pos), tag).commit();
    }
}
```

**Bottom Bar Activity -**

```
public class BottomBarFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_TITLE = "arg_title";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_bar_fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**XML for the Main Activity**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragmentholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML Layout file -

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BottomBarFragment">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If someone could explain how to use this code, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Every Fragment will have its own layout file and you can edit those just like you do it with every other layout file before

Comment: It's not a good UX practice to swipe pages when you are using bottom navigation bar

Comment: I actually suggest to read and learn about android programming in general, before you jump into fragements. But an activity like your MainActivity usually goes together with a layout file. The activity is your class that provides the code that is running and the layout file is the visible part that will be shown on your screen

Comment: @JoeS can you show an example? I am not a beginner at Android coding, ive been learning for some years, i just have no idea how to use Android fragments.

Comment: What do you need an example for? For fragments you already have an expamle in your code. Have you used android studio before? In your general the fragments come with a e.g. `Fragment.java` and an `activity_fragment.xml` just like the auto-created `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @JoeS I have used AS before but I usually don't use activity's. I use canvas's. I'm really confused with this stuff, cause i dont have an activity for each fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three fragements in your bottomNavigationBar. I guess these would be cata, home and settings. For each one you need to create new class.

E.g. for cata:

```
public class CataFragment extends Fragment {

    public CataFragment() {
        // Required constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    //here you would do the fragment specific coding

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cata, container, false);
    }
}
```

As you can already see, they are in touch with a layout file, here the `fragment_cata` file for what you have to create an xml layout file with its name. The layout file can be an autocreated blank fragment layout that you can find in the list when you create new files. That would look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout file you can handle like any other layout file

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding